# How to rotate and position axis labels in Sagemath

Tags: python, sage

By default, Sagemath places the y axis label at the top of the plot, horizontally, with the axis centered under it.  For long labels, this adds a bunch of white space to the left of the graph.  Similarly, it places the x axis label to the right of the axis.

[image: ugly graph axis labels]

I want to place the y label rotated 90° CCW centered to the left of the y axis, and the x label below the x axis.  Googling didn't help, but that could be because the Sagemath documentation site is not mobile friendly.

This is my current code:

```py
var('x y')
g = Graphics()
g += region_plot([x / 2 + 7 <= y, y <= (x - 7) * 2], (10, 57), (10, 100), incol="#ffeeee")
g += plot(x, (x, 14, 57), color="red", linestyle="--")
g.show(axes_labels=["your age (years)", "partner's age (years)"], title="Dateable age range")
```